# How to count perpage using crystal language and kemal

Tags: jquery, crystal-lang, kemal

I have some menu, example:

```
<a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
<a href="/list-book">List Table</a>
<a href="/book/category/">Category</a>
<a href="/book/detail/">Detail</a>
```

And I want to create Quick Actions dropdown menu with the most viewed.
My jquery:

```
var mySession = window.sessionStorage, pageCount;
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
           if(!mySession.getItem("pageCount")){
              mySession.setItem('pageCount', 1);
           } else {
              pageCount = mySession.getItem("pageCount");
              pageCount = parseInt(pageCount) + 1;
              mySession.setItem('pageCount', pageCount );
           }
           console.log('page view count of current browsing session', mySession.getItem("pageCount"));
           var x = pageCount;
           console.log(x)

           $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/dashboard',
              data: {"count":x},
              complete: function(r){
            alert("success");
            }

            });
        });
```

And my backend :

```
get "/dashboard" do |env|
render "views/dashboard.ecr"
end

post "/dashboard" do |env|

body = env.params.body
spawn do
data = {
  "page"  => "dashboard",
  "count" => body["count"],
  "user" => "admin",
}

check_page = DB1["page_count"].find_one({"page" => "dashboard"})
if check_page
  DB1["page_count"].update({"page" => "dashboard"},
    {
      "$set" => {"count" => body["count"]},
    })
else
  DB1["page_count"].insert(data)
end
  end
env.redirect "/dashboard"
end
```

But,this way count all page. I will count page per page every page is click by user. Can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

1. Opening the page the user make a GET request to the app -> route (for example '/dashboard'), accordingly, we can assume that one request as +1 for dashboard page count.
2. In the MongoDB you create collection with two keys: `page_name` like `dashboard_views_count` (for store page name) and `views` (for increment count of views), then you need to learn operator [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) in MongoDB. This will give a simple way to increment counter.
3. After, we make [middleware](http://kemalcr.com/guide/#middleware) for catch requests. It help extract from env page path and write to MongoDB.

In result this will be look at:

1. User open '/dashboard'
2. Middleware catch this request and extract page name from env
3. Middleware write page name and +1 into MongoDB

P.S. Instead of Mongo I propose to consider Redis for counter store.